# Special Pairs till N

Tags: algorithm

### Given a number N (1 <= N <= 10^50), Find number of unique pairs (x,y) such that sum of digits of x + sum of digits of y is prime.

x,y <= N;
Test Case - N=5
output - 6
explanation - pairs are (1,2), (1,4), (2,3), (2,5), (3,4)

## Note - (x,y), (y,x) are equivalent.So, if (2,5) is included then (5,2) is not.

This question was asked in a competitive programming contest.I couldn't figure how to do it.Has anyone got some ideas?

Comment: \pi(10^50) ~= 10^50/ln(10^50) ~= ~10^48, I think it would be a huge list.

Comment: @NeilEdelman rather than primes up to N, think of primes up to the largest digit sum that can be composed with 50 (×2) digits.

Comment: That makes so much more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Observation 1:
Primes you want to consider are smaller than 1000.
(Because sum of all digits of a number <= 10^50 is <= 50*9 <= 500)

Observation 2:
There exists only one pair (x, x) that gives you a prime number. (What is (1, 1), because 1 + 1 = 2, for any x you get an even number, which must be 2 or is not a prime number)

Let's say you have a wizard friend that told you all the results of function f for a given n, where f(x) = number of numbers smaller than n which sum of digits is equal x.

Now find all primes up to 1000 and for each x from 0 to 500 and for each p - prime calculate f(x) * f(p - x).
Sum of the values you've calculated is equal to 2 * answer - 1. (Because of duplicates and that (1, 1) is the only pair (x, y) that x = y and it gives a prime number). So you only check up to 500*1000 possibilities.

The only thing left is to calculate function f.

You can do it using dynamic programming.

Let g(x, d, e) = number of d-digit numbers which sum of digits is equal x. If e = 1, the number you're considering is equal to first d digits of n, otherwise it's smaller.

x <= 500, d <= 50, e <= 1

You can easily see that you have up to 500*50*2 states.

Let's say you know all the previous values of g and you want to calculate g(x, d, 0).

You take any d - 1 digit number and add a digit y for each 0 <= y <= 9. Since you want to get x, it's previous sum of digits must have been equal to x - y. You also want it smaller than n, so you take g(x - y, d - 1, 0) and if y is smaller than dth digit of n, add also g(x - y, d - 1, 1).

Formula for g(x, d, 1):

You take any d - 1 digit number and add a digit y that y is equal to dth digit of n. Then your result is g(x - y, d - 1, 1).

Number of different options to consider is equal 500*50*2*10, which should be enough.

Comment: Could you elaborate your observation 2?

Comment: If you take any x, y, that (x, y) gives a prime number, if x =/= y then (y, x) gives exactly the same number (and is a duplicate of (x, y)). If we ignore the fact that (x, y) is the same as (y, x) we will calculate each possibility twice, except pairs (x, x). However, there is only one pair (x, x) that satisfies the conditions, that is (1, 1). So if we calculate the result counting both (x ,y) and (y, x) we will count each possibility twice except a pair (1, 1). So to get the final result we shall divide obtained value by 2 (because of duplicates) and add 1 (or 0,5 if the division was not int)

Comment: Thanks @Maras for your explanation but please elaborate the calculation of f() function. And also please tell what f(x) * f(p - x) exactly does ?